# Logged in after email validation

Tags: validation, login

Is it possible to login automatic the user right after he validate his email address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the aptly named [autoLoginAfterAccountActivation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#autoLoginAfterAccountActivation) config setting.